# How to make godot infinite background scroll

Tags: godot

In godot i have ParallaxLayer

```
extends ParallaxLayer


var motion = Vector2(-50, 0)
var start_pos = Vector2()
var speed = -50

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    set_mirroring(motion)
    pass

func _process(delta):
    speed -= 5
    set_motion_offset(motion+Vector2(speed,0))
```

this code make the background scroll but not infinite

I dont know what to do when scrolling to end

the official document say i should use set_mirroring

[image]

can somebody tell me how to use this function?

or where should i go for more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirroring expects a Vector2 value, which is the XY coordinates of the "offset" of the mirror. Typically this value would be the height or width of the image you are using as a background (which usually corresponds with the window size), depending on what direction you want to mirror. The example code below assumes a window size of 1080x1920, with the ParallaxLayer being mirrored on the Y axis.

```
extends ParallaxLayer

func _ready():
    set_mirroring(motion_mirroring)

func _process(delta):
    motion_mirroring = Vector2(0,1920)
```